# How does the use of `static` affect the speed of my code?

Tags: c++, performance, static, clang, benchmarking

I was solving an exercise online, and at one point i needed to delete the "" from a the beginning and end of a string. This was my code:

```cpp
void static inline process_value(std::string &value) {
    if (value.back() !='>') {
        value = value.substr(1, value.size()-2);
    }
}
```

Called from this benchmark loop:

```
static void UsingStatic(benchmark::State& state) {
  // Code inside this loop is measured repeatedly
  for (auto _ : state) {
      std::string valor("\"Hola\"");
      process_valueS(valor);
    // Make sure the variable is not optimized away by compiler
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(valor);
  }
}
```

Just because of curiosity I [did a benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/hl6PasrCbXw49VajkknRL0R9Mzk).

- **Compiler:** Clang-9.0
- **std:** c++20
- **optim:** O3
- **STL:** libstdc++(GNU)

While I was at it I decided to remove `static` from `process_value`, making `void inline process_value` that was otherwise the same.  To my surprise it was slower.

I thought that static only meant that the function was just for a file. But [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_role_of_static_function_and_this_pointer_in_C) it says that " 'static' means that the function should be inlined by the compiler if possible". But in that case when i removed static I think that the result should not have changed. Now I'm am confused, what other things does static do other than delimiting the function to a single `.cpp`, how does that affect performance?

The disassembly on QuickBench shows that the `NoUsingStatic` loop actually calls `process_value` instead of inlining it, despite the `inline` keyword making it legal for the compiler to do so.  But `UsingStatic` *does* inline the call to `process_valueS`.  That difference in compiler decision-making presumably explains the difference in performance, but **why would clang choose not to inline a simple function declared `void inline process_value(std::string &value){ ... }`?**

---

EDIT: Beacuse the question was closed because it was not clear enough, i deleted parts that where not related to the question. But if im missing some information please tell me in the comments

Comment: `static` and inlining are not directly related.

Comment: inlining also has nothing to do with this. The information you read was wrong.

Comment: @rustyx: I think the question can simply be re-opened, especially after my edit.  I looked at the asm on quickbench so I was able to edit the question from just asking about a perf difference to asking about specifically why clang chose not to inline without the `static` keyword.

Comment: @rustyx: In the current QuickBench link, I see `callq  2102b0 <process_value...` in the NoUsingStatic tab.  That's not just an allocator.  I think the asm around the call is just creating a `std::string` object on the stack and passing its address.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah yes indeed, got it mixed up with the libc++ version. Somehow clang decides not to inline that one.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: The question has been fixed, both versions are equivalent now.  We can clean up old comments that no longer apply.

Comment: @john: `static` does actually affect clang's decision to inline or not here.  Perhaps with a non-tiny function, it thinks there will probably be callers in other compilation units so there's a tradeoff with total code size.  With `static` / `static inline` there's literally nothing to lose when inlining into the only call-site in this translation unit; other TUs couldn't call a non-inline definition so there's zero possible benefit to emitting one instead of inlining.

Comment: @rustyx Do you think I shoud delete this question and re-ask it?

Comment: @rustyx Ok, thanks for the edit man

Comment: Are you optimizing for size, by any chance? With `static`, the compiler knows that the function is only called in this translation unit and not anywhere else, and it's called in only one place, so it might as well be inlined and the out-of-line definition not emitted at all. Without `static`, the compiler has to assume that the function may be called elsewhere, and has to emit the actual function body for the linker to find, and since it has the function handy, it may decide to use a call instruction rather than inlining in order to reduce the overall code size.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: good guess, but `clang -O3` is optimize for pure speed without much worry about size.  (Although there is still *some* weight given to size; it doesn't always inline and fully unroll everything because at some point that would be slower.  My guess is that the heuristics that prevent overly aggressive inlining are choosing not to here, perhaps considering cost before optimizing away a lot of redundant work).  `-Os` (optimize for size and speed) and `-Oz` (optimize for pure size even at the cost of speed) are different options, and the QuickBench link is using `-O3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang uses a cost based decision whether a function will be inlined or not. This cost is affected by a lot of things. It is affected by `static`.

Fortunately, clang has an output, where we can observe this. Check out this godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/6gqxGs):

```
void call();

inline void a() {
    call();
}

static inline void b() {
    call();
}

void foo() {
    a();
    b();
}
```

In this little example, `a()` and `b()` are the same, the only exception is that `b()` is static.

If you move the mouse over the calls `a()` or `b()` on godbolt (in `OptViewer` window), you can read:

`a()`: cost=0, threshold=487

`b()`: cost=-15000, threshold=487

(clang will inline a call, if the cost is less than the threshold.)

clang gave `b()` a much lower cost, because it is static. It seems that clang will only give this -15000 cost reduction for a static function only once. If `b()` is called several times, the cost of all `b()`s will be zero, except one.

Here are the numbers for your case, [link](https://godbolt.org/z/NAQ4cm):

`process_value():` cost=400, threshold=325 -> it is just above the threshold, won't be inlined

`process_valueS():`: cost=-14600, threshold=325 -> OK to inline

So, apparently, `static` can have a lot of impact, if it is only called once. Which makes sense, because inlining a static function once doesn't increase code size.

Tip: if you want to force clang to inline a function, use `__attribute__((always_inline))` on it.

Answer (score 0):

`inline` is just an advise to the compiler, which may or may not really inline that your particular code.

Regarding to the `static` keyword, if it's applied to a global variable, then it has the file-scope (as you've mentioned) if you compile your code as a separate compilation-unit. So it's even possible to have your static global variables accessible from other files if you compile them as a single compilation unit. This means that in reality, the scope of the global static variables is not the file but the compilation unit (which may or may not be one single file).

But, since you have a global static function, not a variable, it is accessible from everywhere as a global static function.

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @Peter Cordes in comments below, it may be a real mess with inline and static at the same time, so the official doc ( https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline ) says that the redefinition of inline functions (and variables since C++17) must be non-static.

Comment: *inline is just an advise to the compiler* - not just advice: it also makes it legal to define the function in multiple translation units.  (And in fact promises that every TU that calls the function at all will see a definition of it).  So it makes it legal for the compiler to not emit a stand-alone definition of the function in TUs where every call site decided to inline the function.  But if the compiler chooses not to inline the function, all TUs will call the same shared definition of it.  (So it's UB if different TUs have conflicting definitions, IIRC).

Comment: Like for variables, `static` still means that every translation unit has its own private version of the function, which might or might not be defined the same way in other translation units, even though it has the same name. Link-time identical-code-folding optimization could still collapse those separate definitions back into one, but clang's inlining heuristics are designed for code that uses `static` correctly, for single-TU functions. (Using `#include` to create one translation unit out of multiple source files is possible, yes, that's why we have the term "translation unit".)

Comment: @PeterCordes: thanks for the comments, didn't know that it may be a real mess with inline and static at the same time, so I ended up reading the official doc: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline#Description which states that the redefinition of inline functions (and variables since C++17) must be non-static.